# How can I set the value of an input (textbox) using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, input

I've got this input element:

```
<input type="text" id="txtbxYear">
```

...and this jQuery to retrieve the current year:

```
var now = new Date();
var year = now.getFullYear();
```

...and have tried all of the following to set the value of the "textbox" to the current year:

```
$( "#txtbxYear" ).html(year);
$( "#txtbxYear" ).val(year);
$( "#txtbxYear" ).text(year);

$( "#txtbxYear" ).html(year.ToString());
$( "#txtbxYear" ).val(year.ToString());
$( "#txtbxYear" ).text(year.ToString());
```

...but none of them work.

What will work?

Comment: try a console.log(year.ToString()) to make sure it's not null

Comment: Use `val`. Working here: https://jsfiddle.net/fxams0ja/

Comment: Are you sure you have jQuery loaded? Your code to get the current year is pure JavaScript.

Comment: also while in the console, wouldn't hurt to run $().jquery, will return version if it is running on the page

Comment: $( "#txtbxYear" ).attr("value",year); http://jsfiddle.net/wjzctymg/

Comment: If it's pure Javascript, why do I need jQuery?

Comment: If you don't want/need to use jQuery, you can set the value with `document.getElementById('txtbxYear').value = year;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works perfect for me (see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zydLd0fo/)):

JS:

```
var now = new Date();
var year = now.getFullYear();

$('#year').val(year);
```

HTML:

```
<input id="year">
```

[image: output]

If I were you, I would make sure that you've included jQuery either right before the closing `</body>` tag, or in the `<head>` (better in the body), and that if it's in the head, you enclose everything with:

```
$(function() { ... });
```

That's shorthand that checks first to see if the DOM is completely loaded before executing any code. Remember that when manipulating the DOM with JavaScript, you always have to make sure the elements have loaded first.

Comment: The problem was I had all three of those attempts on the page, and thus the one that worked (val(year)) was replaced by the next one which didn't (text.year)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery, it works just fine with pure JS... run the snippet below:

```js
var now = new Date();
var year = now.getFullYear();
var textbox = document.getElementById('txtbxYear');
textbox.value = year;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtbxYear">
```

Comment: I'm using jQuery anyway, so I don't really care which bits I use are "pure" Javascript and which are jQuery.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon gotchya, If you're already using it, might as well take advantage of it :)

Comment: @B.ClayShannon, I think he meant, for this example, jQuery is not necessary, but if it's already a dependency of your entire project, there's no reason **not** to take advantage of it, which is totally reasonable. You can use it or not, but if this were the only thing you'd be trying to do with JavaScript, then jQuery might be overkill. Doesn't much matter either way :)

Comment: Right,exactly what @JoshBeam said. With jQuery you could simply write `$('#txtbxYear').val(new Date().getFullYear());`